# Battery level is incorrectly displayed on Dell Studio 15 with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview, battery-life, battery

After removing my Dell Studio 15's laptop battery charger I'm not getting the perfect battery level displayed in my Windows 8 task bar.

At 82% it displayed 3 hr 32 min and at 75% it's displaying 2 hr 27 min. I couldn't manage my work time because of this incorrect battery level display.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What operating system do you have? What laptop are you using? We're missing essential information here.

Comment: The remaining time displayed will vary depending primarily on CPU utilization and secondarily on other components. The best thing you can do is develop a habit of knowing how much juice there is in your battery depending on the task currently performed.

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me and I bought a new battery on Amazon or eBay. It wouldn't hold a charge. It depends on the usage. If you are using it heavily (games/video), then it assumes a continuous rate and less time. If it is idle, then it calculates with a longer time.

Comment: OS - Windows 8 Preview release, DELL Studio 15.

Comment: @Ashfedy In the future please edit your question rather than dropping important information like this in a comment, thanks.